# Simple symbolic algebra rearranging with Sympy can't preserve logarithms symbolically

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, algebra

I'm trying to use `Sympy` to rearrange simple expressions; although it seems that `Sympy` refuses to keep the result as a symbolic expression, and instead evaluates the logarithm numerically.

Is there a way to force `Sympy` to return the result symbolically?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
import sympy as sy

sy.init_printing()

def rearrange(expression, lhs):
    rhs = sy.solve(expression,lhs)[0]
    return sy.Eq(lhs, rhs)

a, b = sy.symbols('a, b', real=True, positive=True)

eqn = sy.Eq(sy.exp(-a**2/b**2), 0.5)

rearrange(eqn, a)
```

which returns

```
a=0.832554611157698b
```

This is the correct answer of course, although I would have preferred to be told the symbolic algebra result, which (when derived manually) is:

```
a = sqrt(log(2)) * b
```

where log is base e (i.e. natural log, ln).

How can I obtain this result from Sympy please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not a `sympy` expert, but given the limited accuracy of `float`, sympy can't be sure `0.5 == 1/2`. i rearranged the equation a bit so only integers come into play (`Fractions` or something similar will certainly also do the trick)

```
eqn = sy.Eq(2*sy.exp(-a**2/b**2), 1)
```

with the result

```
a == b*sqrt(log(2))
```

but as soon as you have any `floats` in your equation, you will likely get `floats` back. also in plain python: `2 * 0.5 -> 1.0`.

just tried: this also works:

```
eqn = sy.Eq(sy.exp(-a**2/b**2), Fraction(1, 2))
```